# Erro de compilação: The literal ... of type int is out of range

Tags: java, compilação

```
    CadastroDePessoasFisicas c2 = new CadastroDePessoasFisicas("636.363.635");
    System.out.println(c2.getNumero());
    System.out.println(c2.getNumeroValidador());
    System.out.println(c.cpfIsValid(63636363555));
    System.out.println("\n");
```

O Eclipse está acusando um erro na linha 4. Erro: The literal 63636363555 of type int is out of range

Mas o tipo que o método `cpfIsValid` recebe é um long, não um int.

```
public boolean cpfIsValid(long cpf) { 
// código 
}
```

Por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o numero que você está passando é considerado pelo compilador como um valor literal do tipo `int`, e como inteiro, ele excede o [**range de números válidos**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) deste tipo. Se quer passar um valor numérico literal do tipo `long`, precisa apontar explicitamente pro compilador adicionando um `l` no final do valor literal, senão o compilador irá considerar como `int` e vai ocorrer este erro.

A simples adiçao do `l` soluciona o problema:

```
CadastroDePessoasFisicas c2 = new CadastroDePessoasFisicas("636.363.635");
System.out.println(c2.getNumero());
System.out.println(c2.getNumeroValidador());
System.out.println(c.cpfIsValid(63636363555l));
System.out.println("\n");
```

Veja a prova no ideone : https://ideone.com/aQHbcm

Answer (score 3):

O compilador esta tentando analisar o valor do long como um tipo int, no caso você tem que declarar da seguinte forma:

```
System.out.println(c.cpfIsValid(63636363555L));
```